# A problem describing path of an object

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Altitute of a mountain is given by

$$ z = e^{-(x^4+4y^2)} $$

Describe the paths of rain water streams flowing down the mountain assuming that these paths are orthogonal to the contour  lines (level curves) of mountain.

#### Thought:

Call $y_{rain}$ to be the paths of rain. Contour lines are given by $e^{-(x^4 + 4y^2) } = C $. so we have

$$ -x^4 - 4y^2 = \ln C \iff - 4 x^3 - 8 y y' = 0 $$

So, the slope of the contour lines is given by

$$ y' = - \frac{ 4x^3 }{8 y } $$

since it is orthogonal to the path of the rain, we have

$$ y_{rain}' = \frac{ 8y }{4x^3} \iff \ln |y| = - \frac{1}{x^2} + K \implies y_{rain}(x) = A e^{ - 1/x^2}  $$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see any problem!